# Passwords in SuperStreetFighter4 3DS: What's your ID for?

Tags: super-street-fighter-iv-3d-edition

I've seen a lot of questions/answers on passwords, but what the ID is for? Are passwords ok for everybody and ID has no use?

Comment: Your question seems too ambiguous. Could you please add some more details? You say you've seen "a lot" of q&a about passwords with IDs listed. I haven't seen these. Could you please post a link or something to clarify the context? I'm guessing that the IDs in question may be the matchmaking IDs of the posters of said IDs so that you can play against them in the specified 3DS game, but without a context, this question seems too unclear.

Comment: Wow! A comment! I have stopped playing it and I must say, a waste of money... but for sake of community I'll check and try to give you details